# How Can I restore a database to a point of time without Old backup?

Tags: sql-server, backup, recovery

I have a database in full recovery mode with five tables. I accidentally deleted one table. I don't have any old backups. Can I restore the database with five tables?

Comment: How do you accidentally delete a table?

Comment: With a DeLorean?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have any backups that contains the deleted table, you can't restore the database to it's original form.